# Python scraping encoding excel formulas

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, character-encoding

I'm trying to **scrape** websites to csv and work on this data but text formulas won't work properly. I don't really underestand what I'm doing wrong but my guess is the encoding part.

This is the python part :

```
        page = requests.get(url)
        encoding = page.encoding if 'charset' in page.headers.get('content-type', '').lower() else None
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser', from_encoding=encoding)
        example = soup.find(class_= htmlClass).get_text()
        example = "".join([s for s in example.splitlines(True) if s.strip()])
        example = example.splitlines()
        outputList.append(example)
```

[...]

```
    with open(outputFile, "w") as fileHandle:
        fileHandle.writelines(outputFileData)
```

The text in the csv does looks ok but if I'm trying to have some MATCH formulas it often won't find the data. `=MATCH("*13 MARCH*";F1:F20;0)` will give N/A while there is the text 13 MARCH in the column.

I've done many changes and test and I noted that when I use this :
`with codecs.open(outputFile, "w", "utf-8") as fileHandle:` I have special characters in the CSV file and this probably explain the MATCH formulas not properly finding text.

If it helps, I actually import the csv in googlesheet via script and then work with MATCH formulas, the script is :

```
function importFromCSV() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("menulist.csv");
  var csvFile = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvFile, ";");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxx");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('import');
  sheet.getRange('A7:AZ60').clear()
  sheet.getRange(7,1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

I had rubies with the above and added   `var csvFile = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString('ISO-8859-1');` to avoid rubies but MATCH formula still wont work.

And idea what I'm doing wrong with encodoing ?

Comment: Are you able to share a sample of the data / give us a demo spreadsheet with the issue?

Comment: of course ! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oNBiVfjCI553v_VppnoJaffksvj6NklNa_EnNMR6UE4

Answer (score 1):

Try Using, hope it will solve your problem

```
with codecs.open(outputFile, "w", "utf-8-sig") as fileHandle:
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it shows the special caracters in the CSV file. (DU LUNDI 9Â AUÂ VENDREDI 13Â MARS)

Comment: Edit : Sorry this was with "utf-8". With "utf-8-sig" it doesn't show special caractere but the Formula still doesn't work in excel.

Comment: @bobish,  Not quite sure about the encoding, but I looked at your sheet and tried MATCH formula with just 13 instead of 13 MARS and it works. It shows that the real formula is the space character. I also tried SUBSTITUTE formula to remove all spaces in your source text and the results still return *13 MARS* . Hope this is helpful